# Uploading Binary File to Openstack Swift Gives Error

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I am trying to upload a binary file I have to Openstack Swift. This size of this file is 129MB. I am using the Python client for uploading:

```
swift_client = swiftclient.Connection(preauthurl=swift_public_auth_url,preauthtoken=swift_access_token,auth_version="2.0",insecure=True,tenant_name="admin")
with open("/path/to/file/file.ckpt", 'r') as read_file:
    swift_client.put_object(swift_container_name, 'file.ckpt', contents= read_file.read(),content_type='text/plain')
    print "done"
```

This throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1824, in put_object
    response_dict=response_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1673, in _retry
    service_token=self.service_token, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1322, in put_object
    raise ClientException.from_response(resp, 'Object PUT failed', body)
swiftclient.exceptions.ClientException: Object PUT failed: https://abc.xyz/swift/v1/AUTH_123456789abcdefghijklmn/container/file.ckpt 413 Request Entity Too Large  [first 60 chars of response] <html>
<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></h
```

However, when I tried replacing test.ckpt with a blank text file test.txt, it got uploaded with the same parameters. I know this error occurs when the file size is greater than 5GB but what can be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the problem was because of configuration on my Nginx proxy server. Got it fixed by increasing client_max_body_size. More details here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/